# Ubuntu 12.10 - setup a user, when ssh login gives me /etc/bash.bashrc: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, bash, vps

I setup a user on my Ubuntu 12.10 server named "deploy" and I believe i added the user to the sudoers properly.

However, whenever I SSH into the server with this user, I get:

```
-bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: Permission denied
```

What would cause this permission error, and what is the proper way to debug this issue?

SUDOERS:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
deploy    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

PASSWD:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/bin/sh
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/bin/sh
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/bin/sh
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/bin/sh
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/bin/sh
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/bin/sh
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/bin/sh
libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:/bin/sh
syslog:x:101:103::/home/syslog:/bin/false
messagebus:x:102:104::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
whoopsie:x:103:106::/nonexistent:/bin/false
landscape:x:104:109::/var/lib/landscape:/bin/false
sshd:x:105:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
deploy:x:1000:1001:,,,:/home/deploy:/bin/bash
```

Comment: it would help to see what in /etc/password and /etc/sudoers for that user.

Comment: Are you trying to use sudo in a script? Why would you need to have this user in sudoers to SSH into the server?

Comment: This user will need sudo permissions, i disabled the root user and this user will be my user for doing all my deployments

Comment: How did you disable "root" user and what's in sudoers?

Comment: I didnt "disable" it, just only SSH access for root is denied. i added the sudoers to the question

Comment: @DanilaLadner did I add what you needed to see?

Comment: ok, is /etc/bash.bashrc has 644 permissions?

Comment: ls -l bash.bashrc
-rw------- 1 root root 2288 Jan 21  2013 bash.bashrc **looks like 600**

Comment: yeah, fix that to 644. chmod a+r

Comment: Ok, good that fixed that. Now when i SSH in i get -bash: GREP_OPTIONS: command not found

Comment: comment out this line in bash.bashrc type rvm >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || echo ${PATH} | GREP_OPTIONS \grep "" > /dev/null || export PATH="${PATH}:"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10456/discussion-between-joel-grannas-and-danila-ladner)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10457/ddddddd

Comment: @DanilaLadner The `chmod` seems to be the answer to this question, please make it an answer so people can vote on it. The other problem can go to another question.

Answer (score 1):

The permissions of `bash.bashrc` were not correct:

- Before, they were set to `600`:

  ```
  ls -l bash.bashrc
  -rw------- 1 root root 2288 Jan 21 2013 bash.bashrc
  ```
- Changing them to `644` fixed the matter.